# It's a number game and I cant spot the mistake

Tags: python

```
from fileinput import close
```

from random import Random, random

```
print('Do you want to play a game?')
input1 = input("yes or no? ")
if input1 == "yes" or input1 == "Yes":
    print("You have 3 tries to guess a random integer between 0-10. If you guess right 
you win. If not I do. Ready?")
import random
def repeat():

    number = random.randint(1,10)
    print(number)
    guess1 = input('Your first guess: ')
    if guess1 == number:
        print('You are correct! You only needed one try!')
    else:
        print('Wrong two tries left!')
        guess2 = input('Your second guess: ')
    if guess2 == number:
        print('You are correct! You needed two tries!')
    else:
        print('Wrong one try left!')
        guess3 = input('Your third and last guess: ')
    if guess3 == number:
        print('You are correct! It took you all three tries!')
    else:
        print('You are wrong! You lost! The number was:')
        print(number)
        input2 = input('Do you want to play again? Yes or No? ')
        if input2 == 'Yes' or 'yes':
            repeat()
        else:
            close()
```

else:
close()
repeat()

I have no clue where the mistake is, but when I guess number correctly it still says its wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert all guesses into integers to compare since the default input type is string.

```
from fileinput import close
from random import Random, random

print('Do you want to play a game?')
input1 = input("yes or no? ")
if input1 == "yes" or input1 == "Yes":
    print("You have 3 tries to guess a random integer between 0-10. If you guess right you win. If not I do. Ready?")
import random
def repeat():

    number = random.randint(1,10)
    print(number)
    guess1 = int(input('Your first guess: '))
    if guess1 == number:
        print('You are correct! You only needed one try!')
    else:
        print('Wrong two tries left!')
        guess2 = int(input('Your second guess: '))
    if guess2 == number:
        print('You are correct! You needed two tries!')
    else:
        print('Wrong one try left!')
        guess3 = int(input('Your third and last guess: '))
    if guess3 == number:
        print('You are correct! It took you all three tries!')
    else:
        print('You are wrong! You lost! The number was:')
        print(number)
        input2 = input('Do you want to play again? Yes or No? ')
        if input2 == 'Yes' or 'yes':
            repeat()
        else:
            close()
else: close() repeat()
```